# How to add the cell reference (not value) from "last sheet" to the summary sheet formula when "last sheet" changes every month

Tags: excel, vba

I'm automating a Work Sheet(WS) for accounting. [One workbook, one contributor]

Each month they add a new WS that month. [Form Control Button]

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select 
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A1").Select
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Name = Format$(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now(), -1), "mm-yy")
```

I need to add the cell references from the new WS to the summary sheet. The references need to update with changes they make in the last WS.

They have asked me to have the cell references from the "last sheet" added to the formula in the summary sheet.

[The results from the summary sheet are distributed.]

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The question is not very clear - and I don't know what you expect. the INDIRECT formula might be helpful - or you can insert a new formula on the summary sheet by code (using VBA)

Comment: Good morning Edwin, thank you for replying.  There's a "YTD" summary sheet that adds all of the months.   They add new sheets each month. I need to update the summary sheet with the new sheet data (cell references, not values because they make changes).  Does that help? I've already programed adding the new sheet each month. Now I just need to include the last worksheet cell references in the formula on the summary sheet.

Comment: So, this is all contained within one workbook? Or are you building a separate workbook to process timesheets? It sounds like the new sheet is added via a macro? How is the macro triggered? Who is "they" in "they add new sheets each month"? Does everyone in the company get their own copy of this timesheet workbook, and they need to update their own spreadsheet each month? You've asked a very broad implementation question but haven't provided very many details.

Comment: Good morning bl33p, I'm so grateful for the help. 8)  One workbook, one contributor, the results from the summary sheet are distributed. Using VBA I copy the previous last sheet, add a new sheet (paste clipboard) which becomes the new "last sheet" each month. The contributor updates the new "last sheet" for the current month. They've asked me to have the changes in the new last sheet added to the summary sheet but I'm stuck because the "last sheet" changes. The macro is triggered with a form control button. Thank you so much!

Comment: Need some concrete examples of what "adding the reference" looks like in practice.  Adding new formulas into previously-empty cells (which cells?), or adding cell references to existing formulas which already reference previous sheets (what formulas are these?)

Comment: Good morning Tim, in the YTD ws, each cell will look like this "=+'01-21'!E19+'02-21'!E19+'03-21'!E19+'04-21'!E19+'05-21'!E19"  There are 70 cells that need to reflect the new ws updates.  As new sheets are added every month, I need to update the fx (YTD ws) to include the new sheet.  This is beyond my skill level (obviously) so I'm throwing myself on the mercy of more advanced coders.  Thank you for your interest in my dilemma.  8)

Answer (score 1):

**Objective:** To have a procedure that updates the formulas of the Consolidation worksheet after the current month worksheet is added by a VBA procedure.

**Assumption:**

- The month worksheets and the consolidation worksheet have the same structure, i.e.: The values located in the month worksheets in cell `E19` are added into the cell `E19` of the consolidation worksheet. In other words the formula: `"=+'01-21'!E19+'02-21'!E19+'03-21'!E19+'04-21'!E19+'05-21'!E19"` goes in the cell `E19` of the consolidation worksheet.

**Method proposed:**

- Does not use formulas with absolute references.
- Enters the formulas using the [Range.FormulaR1C1 property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1).
- Defines a constant to hold the address of the range to be updated (range provide by OP contains 69 cells).
- Defines a constant to hold a “template” of the consolidation formula.
- After obtaining the month to be processed, cuts and updates the formula template to obtain the corresponding formula for the month.
- Updates the formula range with the R1C1 formula obtained in the previous step.

This is the procedure:

```
Sub Formulas_Update_Month(Wsh As Worksheet)

Const kRng As String = "E19:E24,E30:E35,E41,E47,E50:E51,E54:E55,E58,E60,E63:E64,E67,E69,E71," & _
                        "G19:G24,G30:G35,G41,G47,G50:G51,G54:G55,G58,G60,G63:G64,G67,G69,G71," & _
                        "X19:X22,X41:X44,X46,X50:X51,X54:X55,X58:X60,X63:X64,X67"
Const kFml As String = "= +'01-#YY'!RC +'02-#YY'!RC +'03-#YY'!RC +'04-#YY'!RC" & _
                        " +'05-#YY'!RC +'06-#YY'!RC +'07-#YY'!RC +'08-#YY'!RC" & _
                        " +'09-#YY'!RC +'10-#YY'!RC +'11-#YY'!RC +'12-#YY'!RC"
Dim rFmls As Range, dDate As Date, sFml As String

    Rem Set Actual Month
    dDate = Application.EoMonth(Now, -1)
    
    Rem Set Formulas Range
    Set rFmls = Wsh.Range(kRng)

    Rem Set Formula
    sFml = kFml
    If Month(dDate) < 12 Then sFml = Left(sFml, -1 + InStr(sFml, Format(Month(1 + dDate), "+'00")))
    sFml = Replace(sFml, "#YY", Format(dDate, "YY"))

    Rem Update Formula Range
    rArea.FormulaR1C1 = sFml
    
    End Sub
```

It should be called from the procedure that copies the new month worksheet as follows:

```
Call Formulas_Update_Month(Wsh)
```

Where `Wsh` is the `New Month` Worksheet created by the procedure.

Comment: This is an interesting idea and probably closer to the mark than mine if the formulas Elsbeth is trying to update are summing across multiple sheets.

Comment: Good morning EEM.  Thank you for showing me a more effective way to approach questions (objective, assumption, method).    Your code is next-level epic!  (mind blown).  8)  Thank you, so very much for sharing your time and knowledge with me.  I've added your code to my test file but am getting a run-time error '91' (Object variable or With Block var not set) on   [  Set rFmls = Wsh.Range(kRng)  ].  If you would be so kind as to lend a few more moments, please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.     Call Formulas... is in the Sub where the new Wsh is created with "Dim Wsh As Range".

Comment: In a comment, you claimed to have a procedure that adds a `New Month` Worksheet: «I've already programed adding the new sheet each month». 
It's mentioned at the bottom of my answer that «`Wsh` is the `New Month` Worksheet created by the procedure» (i.e.: your procedure). 
The problem with this statement `Set rFmls = Wsh.Range(kRng)` is that `Wsh` must be defined as a `Worksheet`, instead it seems that you defined it as a `Range`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, all you need to do is insert an additional row into the summary sheet and then fill in the appropriate formulas to reference data from the added sheet. Let me know if this works or if you still have a problem!

```
Sub copySheet()
    
    ' The summary sheet must be the first sheet in the workbook (the leftmost sheet tab, including hidden sheets)
    ' The previous month sheet must be the last sheet in the workbook (the rightmost sheet tab, including hidden sheets)
    
    ' This is a simpler way to copy the last sheet
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    
    Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = _
        Format$(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Now(), -1), "mm-yy")
    
    ' Select the summary sheet
    Worksheets(1).Select ' Or use the actual name of the summary sheet, e.g. Worksheets("Summary Sheet").Select
    
    ' Find the last row on the summary sheet which contains the data from the previous month. There are many ways to do this. As an example, I'm going to iterate through a column and find when the column does not contain data anymore.
    dataCol = 1 ' Choose a column which will be blank after you iterate past the previous month's row
    dataRow = 5 ' The row with the first month's data
    
    ' Iterate down the column and stop when we find an empty cell
    Do While Not Worksheets(1).Cells(dataRow, dataCol).Formula = ""
        dataRow = dataRow + 1
    Loop
    ' Now dataRow should be the first row after the previous month's row
    
    ' Copy and insert the previous month's data *before* the previous month's data. This will extend any ranges that are covering the table.
    Worksheets(1).Rows(dataRow - 1).Copy
    Worksheets(1).Rows(dataRow - 1).Insert
    
    ' Get rid of the copy mode border
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' The following step is not necessary if your references on the summary sheet are absolute or locked, i.e. with the dollars sign like "=$A$1".
    ' Basically we are copying the formulas back to the "new" previous month row we just inserted, since any relative references will be off by one row after the insert command.
    firstDataCol = 1 ' Update this
    lastDataCol = 2 ' Update this
    For i = firstDataCol To lastDataCol
        Worksheets(1).Cells(dataRow - 1, i).Formula = Worksheets(1).Cells(dataRow, i).Formula
    Next i
    
    ' Now do a find and replace all references from the previous month's sheet name to the latest month's sheet name
    Worksheets(1).Rows(dataRow).Replace What:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Name, Replacement:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Name
        
    ' Now the new row in the summary sheet should have all the same references as the previous month, except pointing to the new sheet
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much bl33p bl00p!!!  I'm testing it now in my bu xlsm!!!!  8)  Will update!

Comment: bl33p bl00p, is there a way to target specific cells in lieu of iterating through a column?  Accounting has autosum cells scattered in each column.  Thank you for taking the time to help me!   These are the cells that need to be updated with references to the new ws.  E19 G19 X19
E20 G20 X20
E21 G21 X21
E22 G22 X22
E23 G23 X41
E24 G24 X42
E30 G30 X43
E31 G31 X44
E32 G32 X46
E33 G33 X50
E34 G34 X51
E35 G35 X54
E41 G41 X55
E47 G47 X58
E50 G50 X59
E51 G51 X60
E54 G54 X63
E55 G55 X64
E58 G58 X67
E60 G60 
E63 G63 
E64 G64 
E67 G67 
E69 G69 
E71 G71

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. It's hard to make a routine to accommodate randomly deviating formulas. I have no idea what the context is to understand your comment much less give a solution. What do you mean by "target specific cells in lieu of iterating through a column"? The only purpose of iterating through the column was to find the last row of the data. You haven't given a description of how the data is structured, so I was assuming one row per month but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: You've been very generous with your time and your code is eloquent (to me.)   8)  The ws isn't organized in monthly columns.  It is a series of lists.  Is there a way to update specific cells in the YTD ws?  If you would be willing to show me how to update just one cell, I'll repeat the code for all of the other cells.  The file owner has cells in each column that autosum the groups above it so it is aesthetically pleasing but a hassle on the data side.  Regardless, I am very grateful to you for the time you have afforded me.  I'm learning so much from your code!  8)

Comment: Worksheets(1).Cells(i,j).Replace What:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Name, Replacement:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Name

Comment: That line will replace the previous month's sheet name in a particular cell formula with the new month's sheet name. "i" is the row and "j" is the column of the cell with the formula you want to update. Just repeat that line for each cell that needs updating. Is that what you're looking for?